Can't connect to my MySQL container from another container all running in the same EC2 instance
I am running docker on an EC2 instance. One container is MySQL 8.0 and the other is running a Spring Boot app. On my local Mac machine, when I start both containers, the Spring Boot app is able to connect to MySQL running in another container.
I recreate all that in an EC2 large instance and for some reason the Spring Boot app cannot connect to the MySQL container. Everything is pretty much identical.
Is there anything I'm missing in terms of setup on the AWS for EC2 that is not allowing the two containers to talk to each other?

Hi! Can you provide the docker-compose.yml you used? And if you used barebones Docker commands, would you provide them please?

Not sure what the difference, maybe the version. But to make it work, I explicitly created a docker network and ran the containers to make use of it. They were then able to connect after that.
First, create the docker network:
docker network create my-network
With that, start the docker containers with this flag:
--network my-network

Can you [edit] this answer to include the specific steps you took?  Also see for example How to communicate between Docker containers via "hostname" which may have more details.
